# How to combine cells of data in Googlesheet to a single/consolidate row and remove duplicates?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm trying to consolidate all the invoices that we get from the same contractor to a single row that will have the business name, all the memos/invoices for the week in one cell along with the added total of all the memos/invoices.

I did a SUMIFS() for the total, then I combined all the memos using ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN()), THEN I DID REMOVE DUPLICATES - BUT THAT MESSES UP THE INVOICES(COLUMN L)

See attachments.

Thank you in advance!
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer combines the results of two discrete queries. One to sum the invoice values, another to create csv entries for invoices from duplicate suppliers.

**Result**

[image: results]

---

Use this query:

`=query({query({A2:E},"select Col1, Sum(Col4) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 label sum(Col4) '' "),ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(QUERY({A2:B, B2:B},  "select Col1,max(Col2)  where Col1 is not null  group by Col1  pivot Col3"),  "select Col1  offset 1", 0), REGEXREPLACE(TRIM( TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({A2:B&",", B2:B},  "select max(Col2)  where Col1 is not null  and Col2 <> ','  group by Col1  pivot Col3"),  "offset 1", 0)),,999^9))), ",$", )})}, "select Col1,Col4,Col2 label Col1 'Supplier', Col4 'Invoice #s', Col2 'Total'")`

---

**Sample Data**

[image: sample data]

---

**Breakdown - #1: Sum Invoice value, group by Supplier**

`=query({A2:E},"select Col1, Sum(Col4) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 label sum(Col4) '' ")`

[image: Sum Invoice value, group by Supplier]

---

**Breakdown - #2: Combine duplicate rows in column as comma separated values**

`=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(QUERY({A2:B, B2:B},  "select Col1,max(Col2)  where Col1 is not null  group by Col1  pivot Col3"),  "select Col1  offset 1", 0), REGEXREPLACE(TRIM( TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY({A2:B&",", B2:B},  "select max(Col2)  where Col1 is not null  and Col2 <> ','  group by Col1  pivot Col3"),  "offset 1", 0)),,999^9))), ",$", )})`

[image: duplicates to csv]

Hat Tip: @player0
[Combine duplicate rows in column as comma separated values - Google Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65187342/1330560) on StackOverflow